# How to get computer name and ip address when someone logs in to my gmail account?

Tags: privacy, gmail

Is it possible to get ip address and computer name into my secondary/recovery email when someone logs into my gmail account?

Now what happens, when I log in to my gmail account, I receive email with some details like Macbook was used, Date and time and location(city). And it says that my account was accessed with above details. Now what I want to to also receive an ip address as well as computer name.

I know I can get ip address following [this link](http://www.techhive.com/article/2090509/how-to-find-out-if-someone-has-been-snooping-in-your-gmail.html). But can I somehow receive computer name or maybe some other details of that person who logged in to my account?

Comment: You get what Google gives you - you don't have any control over that email. If you wanted to get more details sent automatically, you'd have to be running the webmail system.